# How can I determine this string value based on the C disassembly?

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64, reverse-engineering, disassembly

So I am working on a "find the password" type binary disassembly problem and cannot quite figure it out.

The assembly is as follows:

function **checkpw**

```
                         **************************************************************
                         *                                                            *
                         *  FUNCTION                                                  *
                         **************************************************************
                         undefined8 __stdcall checkpw(void)
         undefined8        RAX:8          <RETURN>
                         checkpw                                         XREF[2]:     Entry Point(*), main:001012a1(c)  
    00101179 48 89 c8        MOV        RAX,RCX
    0010117c 48 31 c1        XOR        RCX,RAX
    0010117f 8a 08           MOV        CL,byte ptr [RAX]
    00101181 80 f1 52        XOR        CL,0x52
    00101184 80 f9 11        CMP        CL,0x11
    00101187 75 5e           JNZ        LAB_001011e7
    00101189 8a 48 07        MOV        CL,byte ptr [RAX + 0x7]
    0010118c 80 e9 16        SUB        CL,0x16
    0010118f 80 f9 0d        CMP        CL,0xd
    00101192 75 53           JNZ        LAB_001011e7
    00101194 8a 48 01        MOV        CL,byte ptr [RAX + 0x1]
    00101197 48 31 d2        XOR        RDX,RDX
    0010119a fe c2           INC        DL
    0010119c 48 d1 e2        SHL        RDX,1
    0010119f 40 8a 3c 10     MOV        DIL,byte ptr [RAX + RDX*0x1]
    001011a3 40 30 cf        XOR        DIL,CL
    001011a6 40 80 ff 40     CMP        DIL,0x40
    001011aa 75 3b           JNZ        LAB_001011e7
    001011ac 80 c1 63        ADD        CL,0x63
    001011af 80 f9 d6        CMP        CL,0xd6
    001011b2 75 33           JNZ        LAB_001011e7
    001011b4 8a 4c 10 01     MOV        CL,byte ptr [RAX + RDX*0x1 + 0x1]
    001011b8 80 f9 23        CMP        CL,0x23
    001011bb 7e 2a           JLE        LAB_001011e7
    001011bd 80 c1 5b        ADD        CL,0x5b
    001011c0 70 25           JO         LAB_001011e7
    001011c2 48 8d 0c 50     LEA        RCX,[RAX + RDX*0x2]
    001011c6 8a 09           MOV        CL,byte ptr [RCX]
    001011c8 80 f1 f3        XOR        CL,0xf3
    001011cb 80 f9 c7        CMP        CL,0xc7
    001011ce 75 17           JNZ        LAB_001011e7
    001011d0 8a 48 05        MOV        CL,byte ptr [RAX + 0x5]
    001011d3 8a 68 06        MOV        CH,byte ptr [RAX + 0x6]
    001011d6 66 81 f1        XOR        CX,0x4c47
             47 4c
    001011db 66 81 f9        CMP        CX,0x1234
             34 12
    001011e0 75 05           JNZ        LAB_001011e7
    001011e2 48 31 c0        XOR        RAX,RAX
    001011e5 eb 05           JMP        LAB_001011ec
                         LAB_001011e7                                    XREF[8]:     00101187(j), 00101192(j), 
                                                                                      001011aa(j), 001011b2(j), 
                                                                                      001011bb(j), 001011c0(j), 
                                                                                      001011ce(j), 001011e0(j)  
    001011e7 b8 01 00        MOV        EAX,0x1
             00 00
                         LAB_001011ec                                    XREF[1]:     001011e5(j)  
    001011ec c3              RET
```

According to Ghidra, the decompiled function is:

```
undefined8 checkpw(void)

{
  undefined8 uVar1;
  char *in_RCX;
  
  if (((((*in_RCX != 'C') || (in_RCX[7] != '#')) || ((byte)(in_RCX[2] ^ in_RCX[1]) != 0x40)) ||
      ((in_RCX[1] != 0x73 || (in_RCX[3] < '$')))) ||
     ((SCARRY1(in_RCX[3],'[') || ((in_RCX[4] != '4' || (*(short *)(in_RCX + 5) != 0x5e73)))))) {
    uVar1 = 1;
  }
  else {
    uVar1 = 0;
  }
  return uVar1;
}
```

It decompiles **main** function as :

```
void main(int param_1,long param_2)

{
  long lVar1;
  size_t sVar2;
  undefined8 uVar3;
  
  lVar1 = ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME,0,1,0);
  if (lVar1 < 0) {
                    /* WARNING: Subroutine does not return */
    exit(1);
  }
  if (param_1 != 2) {
                    /* WARNING: Subroutine does not return */
    exit(2);
  }
  sVar2 = strlen(*(char **)(param_2 + 8));
  if (sVar2 != 8) {
                    /* WARNING: Subroutine does not return */
    exit(3);
  }
  uVar3 = checkpw();
  if ((int)uVar3 != 0) {
    puts("Invalid Password!");
                    /* WARNING: Subroutine does not return */
    exit(4);
  }
  puts("Correct Password!");
                    /* WARNING: Subroutine does not return */
  exit(0);
}
```

At this point, I can tell the password must be 8 characters.

Also based on the checkpw decompilation, I believe the following is true (assuming variable passwd is a character array containing a valid password):

```
passwd[0] = 'C'
passwd[1] = 's'
passwd[2] = '3'
passwd[3] = '$'
passwd[4] = '4'
passwd[7] = '#'
```

Though I'm not entirely confident on a few of them, I really have am having trouble with those in **position 5 and 6**.

The decompiled function doesn't seem to reference the seventh character so I'm assuming it can be anything, but not sure what this means as it relates to this problem:

```
(*(short *)(in_RCX + 5) != 0x5e73)
```

Comment: `73` (`s`) and `5e` (`^`) are the characters at position 5 and 6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```c
(*(short *)(in_RCX + 5) != 0x5e73)
```

Is comparing two characters at once. This statement is calculating `in_RCX + 5` and then casting it to `short *` i.e. a pointer to a 16bit signed integer (the register used in the function body is actually RAX despite the name of this variable in the decompiled code). It is then dereferencing said pointer to get two bytes at once, and it compares them to `0x5e73`. Of course, this is just decompiled code, so it doesn't mean that the program is actually doing a 16-bit MOV (indeed it is doing two 8-bit MOVs), it is only the C version of what the decompiler thinks is going on.

You can see this a lot more clearly in the disassembly:

```
    001011d0 8a 48 05        MOV        CL,byte ptr [RAX + 0x5]
    001011d3 8a 68 06        MOV        CH,byte ptr [RAX + 0x6]
    001011d6 66 81 f1        XOR        CX,0x4c47
             47 4c
    001011db 66 81 f9        CMP        CX,0x1234
             34 12
    001011e0 75 05           JNZ        LAB_001011e7
```

The check in the disassembly is done with XOR + CMP + JNZ, so Ghidra already xored `0x4c47` and `0x1234` together for you, which is `0x5e73`. This means that in order for the check to pass, `passwd[5]` must be `0x73` (`'s'`) and `passwd[6]` must be `0x5e` (`'^'`).

Comment: Hmmm.... the value "Cs3$4s^#" doesn't work.  See any issues with the other characters?

Comment: @qscott86 well, it works for me: https://godbolt.org/z/5qbjvMG65. You might be missing something else, but the above does answer your question.

Comment: Casting to `short` seems like a reasonable way to decompile that (if we assume this is C with `-fno-strict-aliasing` and without enforcing alignment on the `short`); it's doing 8-bit `mov`, but into CH. And it's using 16-bit `cmp`.  The thing that seems weird to me is `checkpw(void)` when the function takes an arg in RCX (it copies to RAX and inefficiently zeros the old RCX).  An uninitialized `char *in_RCX` makes no sense for the C.  Is this how Ghidra always works, or something that happens if @qscott86 forget to tell it this was using the Windows x64 calling convention?

Comment: @Peter frankly never seen anyone compile with no strict aliasing, except Linux kernel, but... yeah that's plausible. Maybe it is just unoptimized and assumed by the compiler at that opt level? For example GCC w/o optimization should do no strict aliasing, right? Or maybe the code was fine tuned by hand, the disassembly seems very weird. That in_RCX variable hanging on the stack is most probably because Ghidra didn't understand the calling convention on its own.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've seen SO comments about using `-fno-strict-aliasing` for embedded stuff, again because people want to use a compiler more like a portable assembler.  And yes, GCC `-O0` should be pretty much no-strict-aliasing.  Maybe if you did enough weird stuff within a single C statement, you could fall afoul of type-based-aliasing assumptions, since `-O0` only really means don't optimize across statements; spill everything to memory between them, except register vars.

Comment: It's not totally surprising that Ghidra is doing this, as a way to use C-like pseudocode to represent what the asm does.  My understanding is that It's a reverse-engineering and *analysis* tool, moreso than a decompiler trying to make valid C for production use.  (Although hopefully with the right settings, you'd get a func arg not uninitialized `in_RCX`.)